# Is there a way to prevent mildew/mold from forming on vinyl siding?

Tags: product-recommendation, maintenance, mold, vinyl-siding

The back side of my garage is shadowed by branches from neighbors trees, which causes mold/mildew to grow on the vinyl siding.  Since removing the trees/branches is out of the question, is there some type of product that can be applied to the siding to prevent this growth?

Currently I power wash the siding once a year, but the chore has lost it's fun factor so I'd like to avoid doing it. Even if the product/procedure could reduce my maintenance to every other year or every few years, that would be a significant gain in my book.

Comment: Is trimming the trees an option?

Comment: @NiallC. No.  The major culprit is a large pine tree near the neighbors property line.  The tree casts a shadow on the garage almost the entire day.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a good answer for this question as I have the same issue, but on the front of my house which faces not only the road, but due north. Painting the siding is not an option, so some way to keep it clean with less work would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Rustoleum sells a mold/mildew-proof paint called Perma-White.

They also sell a fungicide (Tiabendazole) additive called ADD-2 you can mix into your preferred paint.

Either of those should at least help some.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom paint for boats might work, but there's not a large selection of colors. Bleach or Tilex will kill the mold, but won't prevent new growth.